# TSQL join performance

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My problem is that this query takes forever to run:

```
Select
  tableA.CUSTOMER_NAME,
  tableB.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
  TableB.RuleID
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.CUST_PO_NUMBER like tableB.CustomerMask
```

Here is the structure of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CUST_PO_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ORDER_NUMBER] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ORDER_TYPE] [varchar](30) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [RuleID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CustomerMask] [varchar](500) NULL)
```

`TableA` has 14 million rows and `TableB` has 1000 rows. Data in column `customermask` can be anything like ‘%’,’ttt%’,’%ttt%’..etc

How can I tune it to make it faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody else see the irony in a user calling themselves 'SQLGuru' asking this kind of question?

Comment: Ouch, yes that's going to be expensive because `like` won't use any indexes.  Can you use SQL Server's FULLTEXT search?

Comment: @JustinNiessner - I call it optimism.  SQLGuru plans to be a SQL guru some day, s(he) just wants to reserve the nickname ahead of time.

Comment: Do you really have 14million customers? How often do those tables change? If you don't need live data, you could add a prefilled table and reset it once a day.

Comment: @Lieven Or maybe an indexed view

Comment: It is too amusing to vote down.  Not sure what you are trying to do but I don't think there could be worse way.   It appears PO# has some intelligence you want to extract.   At 14 million rows you need to pull whatever that intelligence is out into a separate indexed integer    status column with a fk relationship to table that has a textual description of the key.  You may need to use a calendar to get response time on the current query.

Comment: @JustinNiessner -- Looks like you didn't understand the question or you have no idea how to solve this. Instead of commenting on the username it will better if you can offer the solution.

Comment: @Lieven - Yes, We do have 14 Million customers. In this case we don't need live data. Can you explain where are you going with prefilled table?

Comment: @BalamBalam -- Yes, it's just a one small step behind lot of business intelligence. There is no FK relationship and this is how they are join. The CustomerMask column has wild card characters which we need to search on. How separate indexed integer will help in this case?

Comment: @Magnus -- How indexed view will help? Can you explain it with example?

Comment: @SQLGuru an indexed view stores the result of the query on disk like a table. And is automatically updated when any of the tables in the underlying query is changed. There is however some drawbacks to using this also. Disk space and the cost of maintaining the view on disk as the base tables are modified.

Comment: @Magnus -- I know what indexed view is but I am not sure how this will help in this case. I need to get all the data based on wild cards in tableB.

Comment: Because search on an indexed integer column would be seconds.  You would only need to extract that intelligence once.   Then as you add new fields they would need to include the integer.

Comment: @SQLGuru But if you had that query in an Indexed View the costly join would not be needed every time you query the view (as it would store the actual result)

Comment: @Magnus An indexed view based on like join might just be too much for the database.  It is worth a try and I am not criticizing the suggestion.  This might be too much chaos to try and harness.

Comment: You do know sub string search is way way faster.   If you are looking for %sldfja or lasdfjl% then go substring.

Comment: @BalamBalam I agree, updating the base tables will get _very_ slow. I would probably go with Lieven's suggestion and fill a custom table with the data once a day.

Comment: This data is obviously not 3rd normal from.  There should be a custID not a customerName in a table with PO.   At 14 million records you need fix your data design.

Comment: @Magnus -- Problem with lieven's solution is filling the data in custom table. I will still need to run the same query to fill the data.

Comment: @BalamBalam -- There is a customerID field in the actual tableA but not in TableB. TableB is a lookup table and only contains search wildcards based on ruleID.

Comment: @SQLGuru - Before making a suggestion, how long is forever?

Comment: If there is a customer_name, customer_number, and PO in the same table then it is not 3 rd normal form as customer_name has repeated values.  Time to learn data base design and fix this schema.  This query is a symptom of a bad data design.

Comment: @Lieven -- Forever here means 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't change what's already there, you can create a new table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableC](
    [CustomerMask] [varchar](500) NULL)
    [CUST_PO_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

Then have a trigger on both `TableA` and `TableB` that inserts / updates / deletes records in `TableC` if they no longer match the condition `CUST_PO_NUMBER LIKE CustomerMask` (for the trigger on `TableB` you need to only update `TableC` if the `CustomerMask` field has been changed.

Then in your query will just become:

```
SELECT 
  tableA.CUSTOMER_NAME,
  tableB.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
  TableB.RuleID
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableC on tableA.CUST_PO_NUMBER = tableC.CUST_PO_NUMBER
INNER JOIN tableB on tableC.CustomerMask = tableB.CustomerMask
```

This will greatly improve your query performance and it shouldn't greatly affect your write performance. You will basically only be performing the like query once for each record (unless they change).

Comment: Yeah, I think that will work. Thanks! Seph. I will accept this as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is don't use the LIKE operator to join two tables containing millions of rows.  It's not going to be fast, no matter how you tune it.  You might be able to improve it incrementally, but it will just be putting lipstick on a pig.

You need to have a distinct value on which to join the tables.  Right now it has to do a complete scan of tableA, and do an item-by-item wildcard comparison between Customer_Name and CustomerMask.  You're looking at 14 billion comparisons, all using the slow LIKE operator.

The only suggestion I can give is to re-think the architecture of associating rules with Customers.

Comment: Re-thinking of architecture is not possible at this point of time. May be in long run.

Comment: Problem is that this query is just the part of one big business intelligence logic which I am trying to fix. Application is written many years back and cannot be changed. I have to work with the data as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Only change order join then faster and enjoy! use this query:

```
Select tableA.CUSTOMER_NAME, tableB.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, TableB.RuleID  
FROM tableB  
INNER JOIN tableA  
on tableB.CustomerMask like tableA.CUST_PO_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? What about the following:

```
Select
  tableA.CUSTOMER_NAME,
  tableA.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
  tableB.RuleID
FROM tableA, tableB 
WHERE tableA.CUST_PO_NUMBER = tableB.CustomerMask
```

Comment: It won't return records where the `CUST_PO_NUMBER` is `test` and the `CustomerMask` is `%est`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the customer mask contained wild cards. I don;t suppose substituting Like for = would improve performance much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE if you care about performance.

If you are trying to do approximate string matching (e.g. Test and est and best, etc.) and you don't want to use Sql full-text search take a look at [this article](http://qualityofdata.com/2011/09/21/283/).

At least you can shortlist approximate matches then run your wildcard test on them.

--EDIT 2--

Your problem is interesting in the context of your limitation. Thinking about it again, I am pretty sure that using 3 gram would boost the performance (going back to my initial suggestion).

Let's say if you setup your 3gram data, you'll be having the following tables:

```
Customer : 14M 
Customer3Grams : Maximum 700M //Considering the field is varchar(50)
3Grams : 78
Pattern : 1000
Pattern3Grams : 50K
```

To join pattern to customer then you need the following join:

Pattern x Pattern3Grams x Customer3Grams x Customer

With appropriate indexing (which is easy) each look-up can happen in O(LOG(50K)+LOG(700M)+LOG(14M)) which is equal to 47.6.

Considering appropriate indexes are present the whole join can be calculated with less than 50,000 look-ups and of course the cost of scanning after look ups. I expect it to be very efficient (matter of seconds).

The cost of creating 3grams for each new customer is also minimal because it would be maximum of 50x75 possible three grams that should be appended to the customer3Grams table.

--EDIT--

Depending to your data I can also suggest hash based clustering. I assume customer numbers are numbers with some character patterns in them (e.g. 123231ttt3x4). If this is the case you can create a simple hash function that calculates the result of bit-wise OR for every letter (not numbers) and add it as an indexed column to your table. You can filter on the result of the hash before applying LIKE.

Depending to your data this may cluster your data effectively and improve your search by factor of the number of clusters (number of hash). You can test it by applying the hash and counting the number of distinct generated hash.

Comment: Naiem,
I am not trying to do string matching.  I need the records based on the wild card in tableB.
Problem is that this query is just the part of one big business intelligence logic which I am trying to fix. Application is written many years back and cannot be changed. I have to work with the data as it is.

Comment: My point was to first use string matching to reduce the search space. For example if you are testing for '%ttt%' you can use SELECT ... WHERE CustomerName contains 'ttt' AND CustomerName LIKE '%ttt%'

In worst case where every customer is a match this will have worse performance but in average you radically can reduce the search space  initially.

But I understand in BI system, you don't want to answer a single query to one request, so this solution might not help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2:** Thinking about it, how many of those masks start **and** end with wildcards? You might gain some performance by first:

- Indexing `CUST_PO_NUMBER`
- Creating a persisted computed column `CUST_PO_NUMBER_REV` that's the reverse of `CUST_PO_NUMBER`
- Indexing the persisted column
- Putting statistics on these columns

Then you might build three queries, and `UNION ALL` the results together:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
         ON CUSTOM_PO_NUMBER LIKE CustomerMask
 WHERE /* First character of CustomerMask is not a wildcard but last one is */

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
  FROM ...
         ON CUSTOM_PO_NUMBER_REV LIKE REVERSE(CustomerMask)
 WHERE /* Last character of CustomerMask is not a wildcard but first one is */

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
  FROM ...
         ON CUSTOM_PO_NUMBER LIKE CustomerMask
 WHERE /* Everything else */
```

That's just a quick example, you'll need to take some care that the `WHERE` clauses give you mutually exclusive results (or use `UNION`, but aim for mutually exclusive results first).

If you can do that, you should have two queries using index seeks and one query using index scans.

**EDIT:** You can implement a sharding system to spread out the customers and customer masks tables across multiple servers and then have each server evaluate `1/n`% of the results. You don't need to partition the data -- simple replication of the entire contents of each table will do. Link the servers to your main server and you can do something to the effect of:

```
SELECT ... FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer1, 'SELECT ... LIKE ... WHERE ID BETWEEN 0 AND 99')
  UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer2, 'SELECT ... LIKE ... WHERE ID BETWEEN 100 AND 199')
```

<sub>Note: the `OPENQUERY` may be extraneous, SQL Server might be smart enough to evaluate queries on remote servers and stream the results back. I know it doesn't do that for JET linked servers, but it might handle its own kind better.</sub>

That or through more hardware at the problem.

<strike>You can create an [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) of your query to improve performance.</strike>

From [*Designing Indexed Views*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx):

> For a standard view, the overhead of dynamically building the result set for each query that references a view can be significant for views that involve complex processing of large numbers of rows, such as aggregating lots of data, or joining many rows. If such views are frequently referenced in queries, you can improve performance by creating a unique clustered index on the view. When a unique clustered index is created on a view, the result set is stored in the database just like a table with a clustered index is stored.
>
> Another benefit of creating an index on a view is that the optimizer starts using the view index in queries that do not directly name the view in the FROM clause. **Existing queries can benefit from the improved efficiency of retrieving data from the indexed view without having to be recoded.**

This should improve the performance of this particular query, but note that inserts, updates and deleted into the tables it uses may be slowed.

Comment: Inset, update and delete are very important. This query is part of nightly process but insert and updates are constantly happening on this table.  Cannot use Index view as this will have significant impact on our database.

Comment: @SQLGuru Don't think there's all that much more you can do then, I've edited my answer with a suggestion but it's not all that practical.